# Nginx Reverse Proxy Subdomain for Node Applications

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, subdomain

I am quite new to NGINX configuation. I have looked through many posts looking for someone else who ran into this problem and found a working solution.

I have 2 node.js web-applications that will run on 2 separate ports (`81, 82` for example).

My initial intention was to use a reverse proxy so that visitors could hit the same physical box, but be served different content based on the domain they used.

I was successful in having to separate sites render based on their domain. One of the applications has a subdomain tied to it (`app.exampleb.com`) and it seems that any time I try to access that subdomain, nginx serves me a page stating "that I have configured the server successfully"...... Thanks nginx.

I have placed the following in my nginx.conf file:

```
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  examplea.com;

         location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    }

    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  app.examplea.com;

             location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
        }


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  exampleb.com;

        location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:82;
        }
    }

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Did you place that config inside the `http {}` directive?

Answer (score 0):

The full config should be this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Place it inside the `http {}` directive in `nginx.conf`

Remember to restart `nginx`

Comment: This didn't work. I do have my servers placed inside the http directive. I'm still getting the nginx configuration. I'll edit my post above to reflect what I'm using now.

Comment: Did you restart it? I know it's a silly question but just to be sure.

Comment: Yes. `nginx -s reload`

Comment: That's weird, try to kill it and completely restart. It should work.

Comment: Same thing. `killall nginx; nginx`

Comment: Are you sure is it getting that config? can you try with `nginx -c /the/path/to/your/nginx.conf`

Comment: Nothing has changed. It must be getting the proper conf. `killall nginx; nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`